# I'm not able to generate Report for my rule in Snakemake

Tags: python, snakemake

I'm trying to generate report for my snakemake rule.

```
rule samtools_index:
    input:
        "sorted_reads/sorted_{sample}.bam"
    output:
        report("sorted_reads/sorted_{sample}.bam.bai", caption = "report/{sample}.rst")
    conda:
        "envs/samtools.yaml" #define isolated software environments per rule
    log:
        "logs/samtools_index/{sample}.log"
    shell:
        """
        (samtools index {input} > {output}) 2> {log}
        """
```

but I'm getting a WorkflowError:
Error loading caption file /home/pulkit/snakemake-2/report/{sample}.rst of output marked for report.
WorkflowError:
Failed to open source file /home/pulkit/snakemake-2/report/{sample}.rst
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/home/pulkit/snakemake-2/report/{sample}.rst'

rule execution does not generate any report.